# Styling Bootstrap Tabs individually

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, tabs

I am working with Bootstrap tabs and was wondering what the best way is to identify tabs separately so I can style them differently — for example, so that there is a blue tab and a red tab instead of two tabs that look the same.

Here's the HTML just for the tabs: (note: I'm using react as well.)

```
<ul className="nav nav-tabs">
            <li className="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">This is the headline of one article</a></li>
            <li className="tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

And here's the CSS I have so far:

```
.nav-tabs>li>a {
    background-color: #3999C9;
    color:red;
    font-family:Fira Sans;
}

.nav-tabs {
    font-family:Fira Sans;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #10122B;
}
```

So not much, haha. Appreciate any tips, whether it's adding in a class somewhere or whatever.

Comment: I'm not following that's the problem here. You can just add a different class name for different kinds of tabs. So it could be `<li className="tab red-tab">...</li>` and so on, and then define the styles for these classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just use css selectors :

```
.nav-tabs li:nth-of-type(1) a { ... } // first tab
.nav-tabs li:nth-of-type(2) a { ... } // 2nd
.nav-tabs li:nth-of-type(3) a { ... } // etc
```